# Qt 5.8 Apple Notification Server Handshake failed

Tags: qt, ssl, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, qsslsocket

i tried it some ours now but i could not get it to work. I want to push some notifications from a Qt Application. Tried to get it to work on macOS Sierra with Qt 5.8 installation and on Pi3 also with Qt 5.8.

I created my push certificate with "fastlane pem" and i tested it with "Pusher" and it works correct. But i cannot get it to work in Qt....

At first is the code i use to initialize and connect the QSslSocket:

```
QSslSocket * ssl = new QSslSocket;

connect(ssl, &QSslSocket::encrypted, this, &IOSPusher::encrypted );
connect(ssl, static_cast<void(QSslSocket::*)(const QList<QSslError> &)>(&QSslSocket::sslErrors),this,&IOSPusher::sslErrors);
connect(ssl, static_cast<void(QSslSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QSslSocket::error),this, &IOSPusher::error );
connect(ssl,&QSslSocket::stateChanged,this,&IOSPusher::stateChanged );
```

Loading the certificate

```
QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(certificateLocation) + "/apns.pem";

const auto certs =  QSslCertificate::fromPath(path);

if(certs.count() > 0){
    qDebug() << "IOSPusher: Certificate loaded successfully";
}else{
    qDebug() << "Could not load certificate : " + path;
}

QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
config.setCaCertificates(certs);

ssl->setSslConfiguration(config);
ssl->connectToHostEncrypted( gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com,2195 );
```

And thats the output i get:

```
IOSPusher: Certificate loaded successfully
IOSPusher::stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState
IOSPusher::stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState
IOSPusher::stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState
IOSPusher::error  QAbstractSocket::SocketError(13)
IOSPusher::stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::ClosingState
IOSPusher::stateChanged  QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState
```

So according to the Qt documentation the error:

> QAbstractSocket::SocketError(13)

means the following:

> SslHandshakeFailedError

And

<del>> the SSL/TLS handshake failed and the encrypted channel could not be established. The sslErrors() signal should have been emitted.</del>

**But** the `sslErrors()` signal will not be emitted in my case....

> The SSL/TLS handshake failed, so the connection was closed (only used in QSslSocket)

Any ideas or samples how i can establish a encrypted connection to apple?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay like so often when i try to get help from anyone i got it now :D

The solution which worked for me now is:

Create the `*.pem` cert with `fastlane pem` with a password (maybe it works without password too but that was the last i tried now and....never change a running system haha)

```
 fastlane pem --development -p <private_key_password> -a <your_app_identifier>
```

Then to connect with the QSslSocket do the following... as before in my question...

```
QSslSocket * ssl = new QSslSocket;
QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(certificateLocation) + "/apns.pem";

connect(ssl, &QSslSocket::encrypted, this, &IOSPusher::encrypted );
connect(ssl, static_cast<void(QSslSocket::*)(const QList<QSslError> &)>(&QSslSocket::sslErrors),this,&IOSPusher::sslErrors);
connect(ssl, static_cast<void(QSslSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QSslSocket::error),this, &IOSPusher::error );
connect(ssl,&QSslSocket::stateChanged,this,&IOSPusher::stateChanged );

QSslCertificate cert;
const auto certs =  QSslCertificate::fromPath(path);

if(certs.count() > 0){
    cert = certs.at(0);
    qDebug() << "IOSPusher: Certificate loaded successfully";
}else{
    qDebug() << "Could not load certificate : " + path;
    return false;
}
```

**Now here comes the magic what it did for me**

Use the private_key (.pkey) file which will also be created with `fastlane pem`

```
//Use the path to the .pkey file from fastlane
QFile keyfile(path + "/apns.pkey");
keyfile.open(QFile::ReadOnly);

//Create the QSslKey as private key
QSslKey privateKey(&keyfile,QSsl::Rsa,QSsl::Pem,QSsl::PrivateKey,QByteArray("<private_key_password_from_fastlane>"));
//Close the file
keyfile.close();
```

And add the private key and the certificate to the ssl config

```
QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();

config.setLocalCertificate(cert);
config.setPrivateKey(privateKey);
```

as you can see here this time i not use the `config.setCaCertificates` method but instead the `config.setLocalCertificate` method. That was a mistake on my side...

At least add the config to the ssl socket and FIRE!

```
ssl->setSslConfiguration(config);
ssl->connectToHostEncrypted( "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com",2195 );
```

**Thats all**

Now the `encrypted()` signal gets emitted! Yeah..